# Find a specific string IF the parameter exists

Tags: ksh

This is an excerpt of a config file (let's give it a name "/var/mqm/mqs.ini"):

```
QueueManager:
    Name=MYEAIP2
    Prefix=/var/mqm
    Directory=MYEAIP2
    DataPath=/esb/wmq/data/MYEAIP2
QueueManager:
    Name=ASIAREPOSP1
    Prefix=/var/mqm
    Directory=ASIAREPOSP1
    DataPath=/esb/wmq/data/ASIAREPOSP1
QueueManager:
    Name=EAIGWP1
    Prefix=/var/mqm
    Directory=EAIGWP1
QueueManager:
    Name=MYEAIP3
    Prefix=/var/mqm
    Directory=MYEAIP3
```

I'm trying to return the value of the "DataPath" (if it exists) when I provide a particular value for "Name". If "DataPath" doesnt exist, I return a default value;

Eg 1: If I provide an input value of "MYEAIP2", it should return "/esb/wmq/data/MYEAIP2"

Eg 2: If I provide an input value of "EAIGWP1", it should return "/var/mqm/qmgrs" (a default value, since there is no corresponding "DataPath")

I've an existing code which provides the input value as QMGRs:

```
for QMGRs in `dspmq | cut -d ")" -f1 | cut -d "(" -f2`
do
    #<to insert code here with QMGRs as input, to be searched in "/var/mqm/mqs.ini">
done
```

Comment: Perl would provide a clean solution for this. Do you have perl on your system?

Comment: nope... no perl on the system... i'm not the admin as well, so cant get that installed as well, unfortunately...

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a ksh. Here I show a quick/dirty implementation using bash. It must be almost compatible with ksh.

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

if [[ $# < 1 ]] ;then exit;fi
export myarg="$1";
export name=""; export prefex=""; export directory=""; export datapath="";

while read line
do
    # We have new block of QueueManager Information
    if [[ "$line" == "QueueManager:" ]]
    then
      # Look at what we gathered so far. If a match found, break the loop
      if [[ "$myarg" == "$name" ]] ;then break ;fi
      # No match found. Reset.
      export name=""; export prefix=""; export directory=""; export datapath="";
    else
        # Block continues. Gather info.
        tok="${line%%=*}"; val="${line##*=}"
        if [[ "$tok" == "Name" ]] ;then name="$val" ;fi
        if [[ "$tok" == "Prefix" ]] ;then prefix="$val" ;fi
        if [[ "$tok" == "Directory" ]] ;then directory="$val" ;fi
        if [[ "$tok" == "DataPath" ]] ;then datapath="$val" ;fi
    fi
done

echo "Name=<$name> Prefix=<$prefix> Directory=<$directory> DataPath=<$datapath>"
```

Comment: thx for the input blackpen... my scripting's absolutely crap, so i'm taking a while to digest your code... taking me a while, but i'll let you know if it helps my cause... :)

Answer (score 0):

When you want to have code for finding one qmgr and call that code in a loop, you can use

```
for name in MISSING MYEAIP2 ASIAREPOSP1 EAIGWP1 MYEAIP3; do
   echo "Look for ${name}"
   awk -F "=" -v default=/my/default/path -v search="Name=${name}" \
      '/Queue/ {if (found) print dp; found=0; dp=default;}
       /DataPath=/ {dp=$2;}
       { if (index($0,search)!=0) found=1}
       END { if (found) print dp;} ' /var/mqm/mqs.ini
done
```

When you have a lot of qmgrs to search for, the work in the loop will be repeated many times. You can change it (exercise!) in a way, that you have code that will read `/var/mqm/mqs.ini` and output lines like `EAIGWP1=/my/default/path` and use that in a grep:

```
grep -F <(dspmq | cut -d ")" -f1 | cut -d "(" -f2) <(yourNewAwkCommand) | cut -d= -f2
```

Comment: thx for the input walter... my scripting's absolutely crap, so i'm taking a while to digest your code... taking me a while, but i'll let you know if it helps my cause... :)